# How to solve this error in Bigquery while i try to store the dataset to GCS

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, append, data-science

Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '5150.595542' as INT64 for field fuel_consumption (position 2) starting at location 249269356 with message 'Unable to parse'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: at least share the bq command of creating table or options when you created table in UI. Also share sample csv records.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redefine your schema: `5150.595542` is not a valid integer.  This is more suited for a numeric/decimal field.

For more information see the docs here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types